# Signed to unsigned with subtraction

Tags: c

I've recently decided to make the leap and read through a bunch of computer science books to better equip myself for the future.

At the moment I'm reading through converting signed to unsigned decimals. I understand the majority if it (hopefully it becomes easier to eventually), but struggling with the following (in 32-bit):

-2147483647-1U < -2147483647

According the book, this evaluates to true. There's a bit about this that I'm still struggling with as I cant see why it evaluates to this.

With my understanding, I know that they are both converted to unsigned values in this calculation due to the first number being cast as unsigned. The first number is therefore -2147483648 after subtraction and then converted to unsigned, or does that unsigned conversion happen prior to the subtraction?

Sorry for the lengthy post, just trying to get my head around understanding this.

Thanks!

Comment: That's defined by the language. As you tagged C, what about your favourite C book is unclear? What did you not find in the standard? For C and without details this can be wrong. And there is nothing casted! Conversion/coercion is not the same as casting.

Comment: Finally, we have a special flavor of unhelpful comments back...

Comment: @Olaf I was assuming it was related to C as the book uses C to talk about Computer Science concepts. I apologise if it doesn't make sense.

The book is "Computer Systems: A programmers perspective". He mentions that adding suffix 'u' creates an unsigned constant.

Comment: Well, dump that book. The concepts of C are not universally applicable to programming. If you want to learn C, get a proper C book; I'd not trust anything this book contains if it already goes wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The first number is therefore -2147483648 after subtraction and then
>   converted to unsigned, or does that unsigned conversion happen prior
>   to the subtraction?

The latter is true. According to [C11 Standard "6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8):

> ...Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

So, *all* of the operands, both the ones for subtraction and for the comparison are converted to unsigned.

**P.S.** For completeness, the conversion procedure is described in ["6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2) :

> ... if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.

**P.P.S.** The answer is assuming `int` being 32-bit long. If it is less than that, then the negative constant `-2147483647` will have type `long` which is higher rank than `unsigned int`, which is `1U` and then the above will not apply and no conversion will be performed (thanks @Olaf for pointing out).

Comment: IMO for the beginners standard is too hermetic and difficult to understand. From my experience in the hackspace - reading the standard makes more mess than eve less precise but more understandable answer

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I agree with you, but a credible reference is needed when giving an answer. Also we are not just saying "go and read the standard", but giving the relevant parts of it and trying to explain it if it is particularly obscure (which is not the case here I believe)..

Comment: I wont be reading the entire text just yet but what you posted was relevant and helped me understand. Thanks.

Comment: With more than 32 bits for `int` both are converted to `int`; no unsigned involved.

Comment: @Olaf I am taking OP's remark in the question "(in 32-bit)" as an assumption of `int` being 32 bit.

Comment: @Olaf BTW, isn't the rank of `-2147483647` and of `1U` the same for any bitness of int?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Hmm, … even then, I'm not exactly sure. Did you consider all possible encodings for example?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Not if `int` is < 32 bits. Then `-214…` is `long` and `1U` `uinsigned int`. But I had to think about it to see all variants. What confuses me is OP seeming to take C's rules as common for all languages. There is no indication he read a C book in the text, just CS. He could not be more wrong. I removed the CS tag to make the question more clear. Not sure that's what he means, though. IMO he needs to read a good (better?!) C book.

Comment: Right... it could be `long`.. I guess I will just add an assumption rather than expand on it in the answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Be careful with assumptions; I'm watching - you know me well ;-))

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There might even be 16 bit `int` and 64 bit `long`. What now? (I know about DSPs with 24 bit `int` and 48 bit `long`, a similar problem).

Comment: @Olaf Same, no?  The negative constant will be `long`

Comment: @Olaf I guess this problem could be removed if the question stated `INT_MIN-1U < INT_MIN`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I had to think it over for all border-cases. That's not what I consider "interesting" and "fun". Actually, I find such expressions problematic and try to avoid them like hell. Luckily they rarely pop up if you have all code in your hands and use correct types.

Comment: That could cause even more trouble. ANyway, I'll leave it here, too late for such stuff. (heck, that might be one of the few true cases a unit-test makes sense).

Answer (score 7):

> The first number is therefore -2147483648 after subtraction

Not quite.  With `-2147483647-1U`, the conversion to `unsigned` happens first.  With mixed `int/unsigned` math, the `int` is converted to an `unsigned`.

Subtracting `unsigned` form an `int` results in an `unsigned` and an `unsigned` is never negative.

---

```
-2147483647-1U < -2147483647
```

Assume 32-bit or wider `unsigned/int`

`-2147483647-1U` is a *int* minus an *unsigned*, so `-2147483647` is converted to  `unsigned 2147483649` and the difference is `unsigned 2147483648`.  Now an *unsigned* is compare to an `int`, so the `int` is converted to `unsigned 2147483649`.  The left is less than the right, so the result is true.

---

[Edit]

Assume narrower than 32-bit `unsigned/int`, yet `long` uses the common 2's complement encoding.  Often seen in embedded 8/16-bit processors in 2017.

`-2147483647-1U` is a *long* minus a narrower *unsigned*, so `-2147483647` remains a `long` and `1U` is converted to  `int 1` and the difference is `long -2147483648`.  Now an `long` is compare to an `long`.  The left is less than the right, so the result is true.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense when I calculate the unsigned values before the subtraction. I did it with a smaller value on paper and I can see how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both are promoted to unsigned and `-2147483647-1U == 0x8000000`, `(unsigned)-2147483647 == 0x80000001`.

`0x8000000 < 0x8000001` is `true`

same with signed only

```
-2147483647-1 == `-2147483648`
-2147483648 < -2147483647
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really quite simple.
According to [6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://6.3.1.8%20Usual%20arithmetic%20conversions) if an `int` meets an `unsigned int` in an operation, the operands are both converted to `unsigned int`.

The conversion formalized as [repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than maximum value that can be represented in the new type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2) really describes how natural signed/unsigned reinterpretation works in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) arithmetic (the most common way, though not the only way, to represent signed integers in hardware).

[Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) arithmetic on a 32 bit signed number works as follows:

- the most significant bit, if set, stands for -2^31
- the rest stand for themselves

`-2147483647` is therefore `2^31+1 == 0b10000000000000000000000000000001`.
Now since it comes into a subtraction operation with `1U` (`0b00000000000000000000000000000001`), you should convert it to a `uint32_t` number by repeatedly adding or subtracting `UINT32_MAX+1 == 2^32`, which after overflow will result in the same binary representation (the rules, I suppose, were made so that the bits could be straightforwardly reinterpreted on 2's complement (most common) platforms), and subtracting `1U` from it will straightforwardly yield 
`0b10000000000000000000000000000000 == 2^31`, which is less than `2^31+1`.

Comment: Reinterpretion of a signed as unsigned is only straight-forward for 2's complement representation. OP did not make clear he is about that. As the book he uses is about CS **in general** and C does allow for two other representations, it is not really that easy.

Comment: @Olaf Well, I have started the answer with the general rules. I'm only using the two's complement example to explain the rules.

Comment: You shoul point that out and that it is not the only representation - not even for C.